# How to post one's own video on Facebook so that it doesn't autoplay?

Tags: facebook, video, autoplay

I would like videos that I post on my Facebook business page to NOT autoplay -- is this possible?

Hours googling this . . . to no avail.

Comment: Facebook doesn't give you any control over this, to my knowledge.

Comment: That's what it seems like.  Thanks for corroborating this.